# upgrading com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService to com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to upgrade an old solution of **google push notification** based on `GCM`, in the further releases `GCM` is deprecated and `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging` is suggested to use.

There are few methods for which I did not find the alternatives in the new release like

1. GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
2. GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
3. GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
4. GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)
5. GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

Moreover I am referring to an old article and in that it has a service that extends `GCMBaseIntentService` available in the `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService` but not in new release

Can anyone help me to upgrade the below code.

```
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager; import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; 
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
    * Method called on device registered
    **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
    * Method called on device un registred
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
    * Method called on Receiving a new message
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
    * Method called on receiving a deleted message
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
    * Method called on Error
    * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
             errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
    * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
    */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
             PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      
    }
}
```

Comment: I am referring article : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think anyone has the time to change your entire code for you. True, a lot of the Registrar methods are not available in the new library, but that's because you don't need most of them. I suggest you start [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) to learn how to use the GoogleCloudMessaging object. It has the `register(senderId)` method, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

> As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features.

Here's the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)